# Handlebars template how to call rest api and await for the values

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Handlebar templated html call below helper but it doen't return values

How to await for the call to get the values

handlebar html which doesn't get rendered in response it's in Promise { < pending > } state

```
          {{#each (GetList req)}}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ItemId}}</td>
            </tr>  
          {{/each}}
```

Helper function

```
handlebars.registerHelper("GetList", function(req, options)  
{
  return axios.post(endpoint + "GetList", req)
      .then((res) => {
            return res;
  });
});
```

Comment: What did you get and what do you expect?

Comment: html page exit before it get promise value...

Comment: The template function returned by `Handlebars.compile` is synchronous, there is no way to have asynchronous code run within the template. You'd need to extend the language to do this, an example package that (attempts) to do this is [handlebars-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-async).